# If $\displaystyle T:\ell_\infty \rightarrow \ell_2: ~T((a_n))=\Big(\frac{a_n}{2^{n/2}}\Big),$ then $T(\ell_\infty)$ is dense in $\ell_2.$

Tags: functional-analysis

> > Let $\displaystyle T:(\ell_\infty,\|\cdot\|_\infty) \rightarrow (\ell_2,\|\cdot\|_2):~T((a_n))=\Big(\frac{a_n}{2^{n/2}}\Big).$
> >     Prove that $T(\ell_\infty)$ is dense in $\ell_2.$

**Attempt.** Since $T$ is linear, $T(\ell_\infty)$ is a subspace of 
$\ell_2$, so it is enough to show that for every 
$x^\star\in \ell_2^\star$ such that $x^\star|_{T(\ell_\infty)}=0$, i.e.
$$x^\star\Big(\Big(\frac{a_n}{2^{n/2}}\Big)\Big)=0,~(a_n)\in \ell_\infty,$$
we finally get $x^\star=0$ in $\ell_2$, i.e $x^\star((a_n))=0$ for every $(a_n)\in \ell_2.$ So, let $(a_n)\in \ell_2$, but then 
$(2^{n/2}a_n)\notin \ell_\infty$ in general, to get the desired  result. Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to see it is that $T(l_\infty)$ contains all elements of $l_2$ that have finitely many nonzero terms, the set of which is dense in $l_2$.

Comment: Indeed: $T((2^{1/2}x_1,\ldots,2^{n/2}x_n,0,\ldots))=(x_1,\ldots,x_n,0,\ldots)$ and $c_{00}\subseteq T(\ell_\infty)$. Thanks!